# Is there something similar to vba macros of Microsoft office(word,excel e.t.c) for LibreOffice in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, macros, libreoffice

I am trying to create a Desktop application in java which can interact with LibreOffice in Ubuntu.

I figured out that we can use C#, .Net and Add-in tool for office in visual studio to communicate between Windows application(.exe) to Microsoft office. But I would prefer create java desktop application(.jar) instead of (.exe) for windows which can communicate with Microsoft office.

I tried installing Microsoft office tools in ubuntu but its not working perfectly while creating documents.

So I decided to go with LibreOffice instead of Microsoft Office.

I want to find similar tools for creating java desktop application for Ubuntu which can interact with LibreOffice.

Any ideas/help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Way too broad. Please spend some time at the [help] and learn how/what to ask here. Not "me vision but no clue, please fill the gap" kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a LibreOffice Basic language.
https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Programming_with_Basic

Answer (score 0):

Java is one of the best languages for working with LibreOffice.  See http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#Java_examples.

NetBeans might be a good choice for the IDE.